# Why I am getting Unexpected EOF? What's wrong?

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer

I am learning VHDL and I am trying to do a simple Generic MUX. It is my code:

**GenericMUX.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity GenericMUX is
     -- n: siendo 2**n la cantidad de entradas del MUX
     generic (n : integer);
    Port ( input     : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2**n downto 0);
              sel        : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n downto 0); 
           MUX_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end GenericMUX;

architecture Behavioral of GenericMUX is
begin
    MUX_OUT <= input(to_integer(unsigned(sel)));
end Behavioral;
```

**MUX.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity MUX is
    generic (n : integer := 3);
    Port ( input     : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2**n downto 0);
              sel        : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n downto 0); 
           MUX_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end MUX;

architecture Behavioral of MUX is

    component GenericMUX is
        -- n: siendo 2**n la cantidad de entradas del MUX
        generic (n : integer);
        Port ( input     : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2**n downto 0);
                 sel         : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n downto 0); 
                 MUX_OUT  : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

begin

    x1 : GenericMUX generic map (n) port map (input, sel, MUX_OUT);

end Behavioral
```

With Xilinx ISE 14.5 I get this error on `MUX.vhd`:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:849 - "C:/Documents and
>   Settings/Owner/Desktop/Xilinx FPGA/GenericMUX/MUX.vhd" Line 53:
>   Unexpected EOF.

Line 53 is `end Behavioral`. Tried cleaning the project, creating a new one but I don't know what is wrong. Maybe some of my code generates this wrong error message.

Comment: Add a semicolon to the end of the line

Comment: This is why all programming languages really need good editors that do proper linting in the editor. Is there a VHDL linting program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steven Goldade said I was missing a semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: I found this link when searching for: ERROR: [Synth 8-2798] unexpected EOF. In my case it was complaining about an error on line 1. The problem was actually that the last line of the file had been deleted so there was no "end architecture;" at the end of the file.